# If electron goes through surface of a conductor, will chopping a wire to thinner parts help the conductivity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, electrical-resistance

Suppose a cylinder wire where according to the classical electromagnetism, charges are flowing thorough the surface. 
If we chop the wire into thinner piece in the direction of current flow, the surface area will get larger and larger, possibly even approach infinity. (a qm joke: which of course, was not considered to be real)

Now it appeared that the electrons have a "sea" of surface to flow through instead of a "lake" of the original cylinder wire surface. Why shouldn't electron felt easier to be conducted? If electron goes through surface of a conductor, will chopping a wire to thinner parts help the conductivity?

Comment: Google "Litz wire".

Comment: Which frequencies are you considering?